# Use type inference when extracting locals with the Visual Studio 2015 refactoring features

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, refactoring

Visual Studio 2015 allows me to extract locals. Unfortunately, it declares them with their explicit type (`Dim ... As TypeName = ...`) instead of using type inference (`Dim ... = ...`, analogous to C#'s `var`).

Example:

[image: Screenshot]

Desired result:

```
Dim v = Math.Sqrt(2)
Dim d = 5 * v
```

Actual result:

```
Dim v As Double = Math.Sqrt(2)
Dim d = 5 * v
```

Is there any way to configure that behaviour? I have looked in Tools/Options/Text Editor/Basic/Code Style, but none of the options there seem to make any difference.

*(It goes without saying that Option Explicit, Strict and Infer are `On`.)*

Comment: Hi Heinzi - I'm not trying to be confrontational here, but just curious - why would you want that behaviour. Surely It is better code to include the type in a declaration? Is there a particular reason you want this behaviour?

Comment: @DavidWilson: For the [same reason](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/125262/33843) that C# users use `var`: There are situations where the type information is just "noise": Compare `Dim stream As ImageStream = GetImageStream()` to `Dim stream = GetImageStream()`. I agree that the type should be used when it is not obvious.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.